# Format the ExifTool output of a filename list from an -if statement

Tags: exiftool

I am running this command to display a list of files with a value of "rotate" contained in the -Orientation tag:

exiftool -if "$orientation =~ /rotate/i" -orientation *.jpg

The output I get is a list like:

```
======== 08.08.20 WYC Races-232.jpg
Orientation                     : Rotate 270 CW
======== 08.08.20 WYC Races-247.jpg
Orientation                     : Rotate 270 CW
======== 08.08.20 WYC Races-268.jpg
Orientation                     : Rotate 270 CW
  135 files failed condition
   45 image files read
```

What I want as output is simply a list of filenames:

```
08.08.20 WYC Races-232.jpg
08.08.20 WYC Races-247.jpg
08.08.20 WYC Races-268.jpg
```

I know I can pipe the output to "FIND /I "=======" to select just the filename line but I would prefer to modify ExifTool's output to just list the filename.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Sailor Guy

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out how to output just the filename with the `-p` option:

```
exiftool -p $Filename -if "$orientation =~ /rotate/i" -orientation *.jpg
```

Now how can I suppress the two summary lines so only filenames are listed?

```
08.08.20 WYC Races-232.jpg
08.08.20 WYC Races-247.jpg
08.08.20 WYC Races-268.jpg

123 files failed condition
 34 image files read
```